# Memory problems with JavaScript + CSS3 animations. How to improve?

Tags: javascript, jquery, memory-leaks, css-animations

I have created a loop of animations. Once one animation is finished, it triggers next one and so on. Seems that when I keep my browser open for 1-2 minutes, it starts to slow down and eating more and more resources until my broswer answers sloooowly and animations barely run anymore. How could I prevent this to happen? Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title></title>
<style type="text/css">
html, body {
    margin: 0;
}
.shared {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
}
img#article-02 {
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 205px;
    height: 205px;
}
img#article-03 {
    top: 227px;
    left: 0;
    width: 205px;
    height: 205px;
}
img#article-04 {
    top: 318px;
    left: 227px;
    width: 431px;
    height: 114px;
}
@-webkit-keyframes article2 {
0%   {opacity: 0;}
10%  {opacity: 1;}
60%  {opacity: 1;}
70%  {opacity: 0;}
100% {opacity: 0;}
}
@-webkit-keyframes article3 {
0%   {opacity: 0;}
20%  {opacity: 1;}
70%  {opacity: 1;}
80%  {opacity: 0;}
100% {opacity: 0;}
}
@-webkit-keyframes article4 {
0%   {opacity: 0;}
30%  {opacity: 1;}
80%  {opacity: 1;}
90%  {opacity: 0;}
100% {opacity: 0;}
}
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    animArticle02();
});

function animArticle02() {
    $("#article-02").css('-webkit-animation', 'article2 2s linear');
    var $element = $("#article-02").bind("webkitAnimationEnd", function(){
        this.style.webkitAnimationName = "";
        animArticle03();
    });
}
function animArticle03() {
    $("#article-03").css('-webkit-animation', 'article3 2s linear');
    var $element = $("#article-03").bind("webkitAnimationEnd", function(){
        this.style.webkitAnimationName = "";
        animArticle04();
    });
}
function animArticle04() {
    $("#article-04").css('-webkit-animation', 'article4 2s linear');
    var $element = $("#article-04").bind("webkitAnimationEnd", function(){
        this.style.webkitAnimationName = "";
        animArticle02();
    });
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<img id="article-02" class="shared" src="article-02.png" alt="" />
<img id="article-03" class="shared" src="article-03.png" alt="" />
<img id="article-04" class="shared" src="article-04.png" alt="" />
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may have something to do with the repeated bindings and jQuery calls. Try this script:

```
//shorthand .ready()
$(function() {

    //cache elements
    var ar2 = $("#article-02"),
        ar3 = $("#article-03"),
        ar4 = $("#article-04");

    //bind once
    ar2.bind("webkitAnimationEnd", function() {
        this.style.webkitAnimationName = "";
        animArticle03();
    });
    ar3.bind("webkitAnimationEnd", function() {
        this.style.webkitAnimationName = "";
        animArticle04();
    });
    ar4.bind("webkitAnimationEnd", function() {
        this.style.webkitAnimationName = "";
        animArticle02();
    });

    //animate
    function animArticle02() {
        ar2.css('-webkit-animation', 'article2 2s linear');
    }

    function animArticle03() {
        ar3.css('-webkit-animation', 'article3 2s linear');
    }

    function animArticle04() {
        ar4.css('-webkit-animation', 'article4 2s linear');
    }

    animArticle02();
});​
```

Comment: Animations have been running for 10 mins now and still running smoothly so this seemed to solve the problem. Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

"transition" and "-webkit-keyframes" all cause the Memory Leak on Chrome.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30841360)